# How to delete current buffer and reopen the next buffer in current window?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I would like to know is there any shortcuts or commands to switch buffer (delete current and reopen next buffer) in current window because sometimes I feel I opened too many buffers? And currently I use bufexplorer and fuzzyfinder.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Try http://superuser.com

Comment: @sje397: the FAQ states that stackoverflow also covers tools commonly used by programmers. So this is IMHO not off-topic at all.

Comment: Fair enough Benoit. Especially considering your answer, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function DelBufferAndNext()
    let s:old_bufnr = bufnr('%')
    bnext
    exec s:old_bufnr . 'bd'
    unlet s:old_bufnr
endfunction
command -nargs=0 BD call DelBufferAndNext()
```

Comment: when current buffer is modified, it cause an error? How could we improve when that happen to confirm yes or no to write and ignore modified text?

Comment: You can know whether your buffer was modified with: `let buf_modied_was = getbufvar(bufnr('%'), '&mod')`